# ASP.NET MVC doesn`t reload css file changes

Tags: css, .net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, rider

currently, I am learning Bootstrap 4 at ASP.NET MVC project (only change index.cshtml, nothing else) in JetBrains Rider and I have some weird problem I can`t deal with.

Every day when I start to write new code in HTML it seems to be okay - dotnet watch run works great, inline styling is okay. But when I change site.css it doesn't see changes, I don't know why. After some time it fixes itself randomly (weird but ok), for example, yesterday I couldn't do anything with CSS until I ran the project in JetBrains Rider, but now it doesn't work. Two days ago it fixed itself when I wasn't using my computer (xD). Do you have any idea what's going on or how to fix it? I didn't find anything interesting on Google

P.S. I updated JetBrains IDE to the latest version but nothing is changed

Answer (score 2):

Its browser-cache related. You should cache bust your css file ( add rand number or guid at the end of your css stylesheet declaration, ex : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=3.4.1">`  3.4.1 should be generate randomly. ). Before doing that, you can also clear-cache or hard reload your page and you should see your changes.

Take a look at : https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/